# R create column combining information from two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
structure(list(t1errser_1 = c(5, 2, 3, 4, 4, NA, 3, NA, 4, 2), 
    t1errser_2 = c(NA, 4, 3, 5, NA, NA, 4, NA, 4, 2), t1errser_3 = c(2, 
    3, 3, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 4), t1errser_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA), t1errser_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2), t1errser_6 = c(5, 4, NA, NA, 5, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, 3), t1errser_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
    NA, NA, 2), t1errser_8 = c(NA, 4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 4, NA, 
    3), t1errser_9 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    t1errsel = c(6, 2, 2, 2, 1, 9, 6, 8, 1, 5)), row.names = c(4L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I have nine columns (`t1errser_1` to `t1errser_9`) and one column `t1errsel`. What I would like to have is a new column called `t1errsel_ser`. This column should have the information from `errser_1` to `errser_9` for the `errser_x` that is specified in `errsel`. So for example for the first column `t1errsel_ser` should be `5` (`errsel` for that column is `6` and `errser_6` = `5`), for the second column `4` (errsel is 2 and `errser_2` = `4`), then `3` and so on...

Hope this is clear. Please ask if additional info is needed.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapply` using `[` and provide `x[1:9]` to `asplit` and use `x$t1errsel` for subsetting.

```
x$t1errsel_ser <- mapply("[", asplit(x[1:9], 1), x$t1errsel)
x$t1errsel_ser
# [1] 5 4 3 5 4 5 3 4 4 2
```

or use *matrix sub-setting*:

```
x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x$t1errsel)]
# [1] 5 4 3 5 4 5 3 4 4 2
```

Comment: Just asking for my own knowledge, Can it be solved even when columns are not arranged sequentially, say `df <- df[c(sample(1:9, 9), 10)]`

Comment: Then you need to order it like: `x[cbind(1:nrow(x), order(names(x)[1:9])[x$t1errsel])]`

Comment: Alternative using names: `mapply("[", asplit(x[1:9], 1), paste0("t1errser_", x$t1errsel))'`

Answer (score 2):

Following the very interesting solutions proposed by dear @AnilGoyal, here is another variation of `purrr` package functions which you can use for your purpose. Here I used `map2` function because basically we are dealing with two variables. One is the column `t1errsel` which contains the indices and the other is the sequence of rows of `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(t1errsel_ser = map2(t1errsel, 1:nrow(df), ~ df[.y, .x])) %>%
  select(t1errsel_ser)

   t1errsel_ser
4             5
6             4
7             3
8             5
9             4
10            5
11            3
13            4
15            4
16            2
```

Comment: Good one.  I was also trying with map but couldn't succeed

Comment: Thank you very much. I went down the same dark path too. But following our discussion with akrun yesterday, I realized in this case when I only use `.x` to subset the data frame it extracts the whole column. Something akrun specifically mentioned in another context. So I figured out a way to subset the desired column value in a its corresponding row.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I also thought about `imap` beside `map` but to know avail.

Comment: I think second (invisible) argument in imap will be `1:ncol(df)` instead of `1:nrow(df)`.  Incidentally df here consists of 10 rows and 10 cols.

Comment: @AnilGoyal So I think that would not be a very stable solution for future variation of data. I also don't think it can't be done by iterating with only 1 variable.

Comment: but `df %>% mutate(t1errsel_ser = imap(t1errsel, ~ df[.y, .x]))` is working fine in my window.  pls recheck

Comment: @AnilGoyal Yes you are right. But if the number of columns is not equal to the number of rows it won't lead to the desired output.

Comment: Yes because seq_along runs at col length.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a `tidyverse`. The last colum `value` contains the expected values.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_")) %>% 
  mutate(name2 =str_split(name, "_", simplify = F) %>% map_chr(2)) %>% 
  filter(t1errsel == name2) %>% 
  select(., value) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
   t1errser_1 t1errser_2 t1errser_3 t1errser_4 t1errser_5 t1errser_6 t1errser_7 t1errser_8 t1errser_9 t1errsel value
1           5         NA          2         NA         NA          5         NA         NA          1        6     5
2           2          4          3         NA         NA          4         NA          4         NA        2     4
3           3          3          3         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        2     3
4           4          5          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5         NA        2     5
5           4         NA         NA         NA          3          5         NA         NA         NA        1     4
6          NA         NA          4          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5        9     5
7           3          4         NA          5         NA          3          4          5         NA        6     3
8          NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA          4         NA        8     4
9           4          4         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        1     4
10          2          2          4         NA          2          3          2          3         NA        5     2
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** though the above answer has already been accepted and problem has been solved, I was wondering whether we can get it even when the columns are not in order.  After a several hours of pounding my head on keyboard, I got an easy solution.  Let's say the columns are not in order.

```
df <- df[c(sample(1:9, 9), 10)]
df
   t1errser_9 t1errser_6 t1errser_5 t1errser_2 t1errser_4 t1errser_3 t1errser_1 t1errser_7 t1errser_8 t1errsel
4           1          5         NA         NA         NA          2          5         NA         NA        6
6          NA          4         NA          4         NA          3          2         NA          4        2
7          NA         NA         NA          3         NA          3          3         NA         NA        2
8          NA         NA         NA          5         NA          4          4         NA          5        2
9          NA          5          3         NA         NA         NA          4         NA         NA        1
10          5         NA         NA         NA          4          4         NA         NA         NA        9
11         NA          3         NA          4          5         NA          3          4          5        6
13         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA          4        8
15         NA         NA         NA          4         NA         NA          4         NA         NA        1
16         NA          3          2          2         NA          4          2          2          3        5
```

Now this simple `dplyr` strategy will give you what exactly is desired.

```
df %>% mutate(t1errsel_ser = glue::glue('t1errser_{t1errsel}')) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(t1errsel_ser = get(t1errsel_ser))

# A tibble: 10 x 11
# Rowwise: 
   t1errser_9 t1errser_6 t1errser_5 t1errser_2 t1errser_4 t1errser_3 t1errser_1 t1errser_7 t1errser_8 t1errsel     d
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1          1          5         NA         NA         NA          2          5         NA         NA        6     5
 2         NA          4         NA          4         NA          3          2         NA          4        2     4
 3         NA         NA         NA          3         NA          3          3         NA         NA        2     3
 4         NA         NA         NA          5         NA          4          4         NA          5        2     5
 5         NA          5          3         NA         NA         NA          4         NA         NA        1     4
 6          5         NA         NA         NA          4          4         NA         NA         NA        9     5
 7         NA          3         NA          4          5         NA          3          4          5        6     3
 8         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA          4        8     4
 9         NA         NA         NA          4         NA         NA          4         NA         NA        1     4
10         NA          3          2          2         NA          4          2          2          3        5     2
```

**Earlier answer** A one liner solution through `purrr::pmap()`

```
purrr::pmap_df(df, ~c(list(...), setNames(list(...)[..10], 't1errsel_ser')))

# A tibble: 10 x 11
   t1errser_1 t1errser_2 t1errser_3 t1errser_4 t1errser_5 t1errser_6 t1errser_7 t1errser_8 t1errser_9 t1errsel t1errsel_ser
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
 1          5         NA          2         NA         NA          5         NA         NA          1        6            5
 2          2          4          3         NA         NA          4         NA          4         NA        2            4
 3          3          3          3         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        2            3
 4          4          5          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5         NA        2            5
 5          4         NA         NA         NA          3          5         NA         NA         NA        1            4
 6         NA         NA          4          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5        9            5
 7          3          4         NA          5         NA          3          4          5         NA        6            3
 8         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA          4         NA        8            4
 9          4          4         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        1            4
10          2          2          4         NA          2          3          2          3         NA        5            2
```

OR `easier to understand` one

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(t1errsel_ser = pmap(df, ~ list(...)[..10]))

   t1errser_1 t1errser_2 t1errser_3 t1errser_4 t1errser_5 t1errser_6 t1errser_7 t1errser_8 t1errser_9 t1errsel t1errsel_ser
4           5         NA          2         NA         NA          5         NA         NA          1        6            5
6           2          4          3         NA         NA          4         NA          4         NA        2            4
7           3          3          3         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        2            3
8           4          5          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5         NA        2            5
9           4         NA         NA         NA          3          5         NA         NA         NA        1            4
10         NA         NA          4          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5        9            5
11          3          4         NA          5         NA          3          4          5         NA        6            3
13         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA          4         NA        8            4
15          4          4         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        1            4
16          2          2          4         NA          2          3          2          3         NA        5            2
```

Comment: I am glad that I am not alone in this. I can totally relate to that several hours of pounding your head and ... . These solutions are great. Well done.

Comment: Anil please check out my solution. After 1 hour I could find how we could do it without `pmap`.